# Scope of "charset" in Content-Type HTTP header

Tags: http

HTTP responses generated by the Pyramid web framework append `; charset=UTF-8` to the `Content-Type` HTTP header.  For example,

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

[Section 14.17 of RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) gives an example of this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4
```

However, there's no description of the role of this `charset` "property".  What scope does this have, and who interprets it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It defines the character encoding of the entity being transferred, and can be interpreted by the remote user. Pyramid is telling everyone that it only ever talks to people in UTF-8, rather than defaulting to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Basically it tells the client that the `text/html` content (the decoded and decompressed response body) itself is encoded in `UTF-8`?  This may or may not be redundant with some definitions.  For example, section 3 of [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) gives a clear way to unambiguously determine the encoding of JSON text.  Also, XML documents can specify the encoding in the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` header.

Comment: That's exactly what it's saying - of course, XML files can be transmitted by other means, or stored on disk which is what some of these extra declarations are about.